# mixed model with non-normally distributed data

Tags: mixed-model

I have a database in which a group of patients was assigned to one of two treatment arms. I have to find out if there is a difference in the evolution of a particular biomarker between these two treatment modalities along the study (3 repeated measurements at 3 different time-points). 
My first problem is that I have missing values (because some of the patients died, were lost to follow-up...etc). And my second one is that this biomarker has a non-normally distribution.
Is it correct to use a generalized linear mixed model to analyse the data? Do I have to make some corrections because of the distribution of the data?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please give more information on what you mean by "non-normally". Do you mean it has outliers? That is only positive? That is discrete? etc. Generally speaking, yes, your intuition is correct. You could use a 'gamma' or a 'inverse-gaussian' family if you have only positive values with some extreme values (see `?family`). Depending on your encoding missing values should not be a massive problem for a GLMM as they can be assumed [MCAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data). Nevertheless if you are doing survival analysis the missing value mechanism should be explored further.

Comment: This biomarker has only positive values, and these values are positively skewed. I can do the GLMM analysis without any other corrections? I must say I am more familiar with SPSS than with R (but if you could describe the exact steps, I think I could do this analysis in R too). Thank you